# Binding programmatically to a syncfusion NeedPointer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am trying to bind without success a property called `PointerValue` to a `NeedlePointer.Value` progmatically but seem to have got lost somewhere.

The xamarin app basically has a gauge and a start button when the start button is pressed I start the timer. Upon timer elapsed the needle value should increase by on. Easy in XAML but cant figure out how to convert this to code `<gauge:NeedlePointer Value="{Binding PointerValue}"`

```
public class StopWatchPage : BaseContentPage
{
    private Timer timer;

    private double PointerValue
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(PointerValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(PointerValueProperty, value);
    }

    private static readonly BindableProperty PointerValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("PointerValue", 
           typeof(double), typeof(StopWatchPage), 0d);

    public StopWatchPage()
    {
        this.BindingContext = this;

        var needlePointer = new NeedlePointer
        {
            Value = PointerValue
        };
        needlePointer.SetBinding(
            PointerValueProperty, nameof(PointerValue));

        var scale = new Scale{...};
        scale.Pointers.Add(needlePointer);
        scales.Add(scale);
        circularGauge.Scales = scales;

        ... add gauge to Content etc...
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PointerValue += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, although the actual name of `ValueProperty` might be different depending on how `NeedlePointer` is implemented.  The first argument is the name of the control property that you are binding to (the target), and the second is the name of the value property acts as the source.

```
needlePointer.SetBinding(NeedlePointer.ValueProperty, "PointerValue");
```

however, if you want the UI to update dynamically, you will also need to have your `BindingContext` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

There is no need to create a `BindableProperty`

Answer (score 0):

Solution thanks to @Jason pointing me to the fact that I needed a model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so code changed to

```
public class StopWatchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double PointerValue { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class StopWatchPage : BaseContentPage
{
    private Timer timer;
    private readonly StopWatchViewModel model = new StopWatchViewModel();

    public StopWatchPage()
    {
        BindingContext = model;
        ...
        needlePointer.SetBinding(NeedlePointer.ValueProperty, 
          nameof(model.PointerValue));
        ...
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.PointerValue += 1;
    }
}
```